# WP rewrite_rule match is empty (With Exclude Pattern)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, wp-rewrite

i am struggline with the WP add_rewrite_rule and love any feedback and assistance.

my category pages are:

- category/catname1
- category/catname2/

and my products  pages are:

- category/product/productname1
- category/product/productname2/

as the default WP rewrite rules  has a conflict with using the same pemalink base for category and product i am trying to  get around this.

I was able to remove all product category rules and  want to add a new rule  where the URI starts with **'category'** but does not have **'product'** string in it.
I think i got the rewrite rule right and it catches it, however  the **$matches[1]** is always empty and not forwarding the  actual category name.

```
add_action('init', function(){
    add_filter('product_cat_rewrite_rules', '__return_empty_array');
    
    add_rewrite_rule('category\/(?!product).*\/?$', 'index.php?tester=$matches[1]', 'top');
    

    
}, 10, 0);


function custom_rewrite_tag( $vars ) {
add_rewrite_tag( '%tester%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_tag');
```

When i print out the query_vars for that page i alwasy get:
`Array ( [tester] => )`

Comment: Your expression is not actually _capturing_ anything. Make that `.*` into `(.*)`

Comment: @CBroe thanks, but when i add ```(.*)``` then page ```category/test/``` is catched. But page ```category/product/product-2/```  is detected as a category and query_vars that are returned are ```Array ( [category_name] => product/product-2 )```